# What is meant by effective nuclear interactions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, nuclear-physics, astrophysics, neutron-stars

I am new to astrophysics... I am confused by the term effective nuclear interaction SLy of the Skryme type. Would anyone define me briefly that phrase and some reference related to it?

Answer (score 1):

Effective nuclear interactions are functional that have been introduced by physicists (Tony Skyrme) in the last century to study nuclear structure with self-consistent approaches (e.g. Hartree-Fock).

The most popular one is the Skyrme interaction:

[image: Skyrme potential]

You can see that there are coefficients like $t_0$, ... 
These coefficients are fitted from experimental informations such as nuclear masses and radii.

Nowadays, we can find a lot of different functionals. We can cite the Skyrme-Lyon family (what you called "SLy") but we also could distinguish SLy4 and SLy7. These functionals are very successful in nuclear astrophysics. Indeed, if you show interest in nuclear astrophysics, you probably know that a lot of compact objects such as neutron stars are very neutron-rich. The problem is that we can't have informations on neutron-rich systems in the lab. SLy4 and SLy7 were introduced to fit experimental masses as well as neutron matter.

[Relevant paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0006135).